# spark dataframe multiple columns into a list/array

Tags: list, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a spark (version 2.2) dataframe `dtfBAIDate` as below.

[image: dataframe dtfBAIDate]

I would like to convert them into a list/array, `list((A,xxxxxx),(B,xxxxxx),(C,xxxxxx),(D,xxxxxx))`. So later I could loop the elements in it

```
lisBAIDate.foreach(e=> {
  val (strBAI, strDate) = e
  println(strBAI + " Date=" + strDate)
...
})
```

The following codes made it happen. But is there a neater way of constructing a list/array with 2 strings per element?

```
  val arrBAI=dtfBAIDate.collect.map(_(0).toString)
    val arrDate=dtfBAIDate.collect.map(_(1).toString)
    val lisBAIDate=(arrBAI zip arrDate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val lisBAIDate= dtfBAIDate.collect.map(x => (x(0).toString,x(1).toString))
```